# Intercept /paste/ event in a modal popup

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to automatically intercept the paste (or any other) event in the dynamic html generated in modal popups?

I tried

```
document.onpaste = function(e){
    console.log("pasted!!!");
}
```

The problem that if the onPaste happens in a popup (modal) window, it is not intercepted...

I explain: I try to implement a addin javascript to facilitate the paste in forms (fill in one paste multiple inputs), [here a sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pastify?file=index.js)

I have no control over the how popup opens...

So if I take any abstract page that opens a modal popup. What code should I add to the page that the inputs in that popup listen to my event (and log "pasted!" console log)

Comment: What kind of popup window? Some actual different page from your own or just "modal" implementation?

Comment: @Justinas: modal form

Comment: I see your code only works for first element, because `querySelector` returns only first element by selector

Comment: @Justinas the console.log ("pasted") does not trigger when pasting in modal

Comment: I see no modal forms in your example

Comment: @Justinas the example has no modals, but I want to apply same logic to any page, including that opens modal windows

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only work for first element in page, because you use `querySelector`.

Use `querySelectorAll` and add events to all inputs:

```js
const pastify = function(e) {
  console.log('Pasted !!!');

  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  let input = e.target;
  let data = e.clipboardData;
  const texts = String(data.getData('Text'))
    .split(/\r?\n/)
    .map((t) => t.trim());
  let form = input.form;
  let formInputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (let i = 0; i < formInputs.length && texts[i]; i++) {
    formInputs[i].value = texts[i];
  }
};

(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(input) {
    input.addEventListener('paste', pastify);
  })
})();
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="paste multiline here"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="or here"><br>
  <label for="city">City:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="Moscow">
</form>
```

Comment: the problem is not fist input, the problem is the modal form, the document is not listening on dynamic html generated after the page loaded

Comment: @serge Yes, you must re-apply all events to dynamic elements (or use jQuery `.on`)

Comment: that is the problem. Take any abstract page that opens popup. What code should I add to the page that the inputs in that popup listen to my event (and log "pasted!" console log)

Comment: to fix the code in the stackblitz is irrelevant until that code is not executed at all in a modal popup, because any paste event is caught